# Creating Synch Point In TFS Source Tree Development Cycle

Tags: tfs

Our development cycle rarely requires a branch so we have what tfs appears to consider a single, never-ending development cycle.  Our problem is that each build includes an ever increasing long "Generating list of changesets and updating work items" step that includes all changesets/work items back to day 1.

What is the proper step that we need to perform to formally lock and label (wrong terms I'm sure) the source tree so that a new cycle of changesets and work items can begin.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are your builds completely succeeding? No failing unit tests?

Comment: I believe that there are 1 or 2 unit tests that routinely fail.  The builds complete with a mixed result (combined green check and red x if I remember correctly).

Comment: Ok - I took the hint and tried turning off build tests and the Change Set and Work Items dropped to zero.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: I suffered from a similar situation. There were two unit tests that always failed, and nobody had time to fix them.